# p5.js mousePressed stop after first iteration

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I need just the first click. I cannot do mouseClicked() because it does not allow you to get the mouse button clicked (left or right). Anyone know any workarounds? I'm not opposed to doing this in vanilla js but I was wondering if anyone with more knowledge in p5 than me knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if `mousePressed` *once* via this

```
int pressed = false;
mousePressed(){
    if(!pressed){
        //run code
        pressed=true;
    }
};
mouseReleased(){
    pressed=false;
};
```

As i learned how to code on a processingJS on khan academy which is extremely close to p5.js

**EDIT** looking at https://processing.org/tutorials/interactivity/
I learned that it isnt `button` it is `mouseButton`
so if you run

```
mouseClicked(){
    println(mouseButton);  
   //0 === left
   //1 === right
}
```